# How to print the value of the array in MongoDB query inside PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, google-maps, twitter-streaming-api

Somehow I managed to encase my coordinates into an array

```
  <?php

  $document = $collection->find([],['_id' => 0,'coordinates.coordinates' => 1]);

  $array = iterator_to_array($document, false);

  foreach($document as $k => $row){
  echo json_encode($row);
  }

  ?>
```

which outputs the following.There are 3 documents inside my collection and all of them are identical (for testing purposes).

```
{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}}{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}}{"coordinates":{"coordinates":[121.9197351,11.96795331]}}
```

I am trying to figure out how to echo/print/use the individual longitude and latitude to visualize in google maps api since they are inside an array. But printing them using for-loop replacing the foreach code above with this code doesn't work

```
$length = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
print $array[$i];
}
```

I'm quite new to both platforms so please bear with me thank you.

Here is the snippet of my document from twitter stream

```
"coordinates": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [121.9197351, 11.96795331]
},
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It outputs the following error

`Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmaps_thesis\main.php on line 26
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmaps_thesis\main.php on line 26
Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmaps_thesis\main.php on line 26
Array`

@NicoHaase

Comment: Ah, yeah, because `$array[$i]` is still an array. So you should define how the output should look like and then echo it, eg. through `echo $array[$]['coordinates']`

Comment: Something like this `echo $array[$i]['coordinates'];` inside the for-loop? @Nico

Comment: Your `$document` is a cursor to the 3 documents in your example. Does http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php help?

Comment: Actually I've read that link 2 days ago and still i couldn't understand a thing in there sorry. I'm just used to relational databases where I can handle each specific attribute using an array. I'm trying to do the same using mongoDB where I can retrieve each of the longitude and latitude in an array. Something like array[0] for latitude, and array[1] for longitude. @DaveCoast

Comment: Karl, just try it :) And yes, if you want to print only data for a single document, you should do it within the loop

Comment: @NicoHaase yes I did but the error is still the same from before :(

Comment: Anyways I've looked into this site http://www.svennerberg.com/2012/03/adding-multiple-markers-to-google-maps-from-json/ and maybe I could substitute the `var` in the site to 'var_dump()`? I'm on my phone as of now.